# VBA EXCEL input argument from ContextMenu.Controls

Tags: excel, vba

How can I pass input argument through CustomMenu item:
    Sub something()
    ...variables...

```
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=2)
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "MyFunctionWithParameter" 'Here somehow I need to provide rng as input argument!
    .FaceId = 59
    .Caption = "Spoji R brojeve"
    .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
End With
End sub
Function MyFunctionWithParameter (rng)
    MsgBox(rng)
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not a duplicate, simply because of its different logic, and concept.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this. But please provide some more information, it's very hard to understand what you have to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

`CommandBarButton.OnAction` is a string and cannot contain any objects. The only thing you could do is handover the address of the range as a string:

```
...
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=2)
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "MyFunctionWithParameter(""" & rng.Address(External:=True) & """)" 'Here somehow I need to provide rng as input argument!
    .FaceId = 59
    .Caption = "Spoji R brojeve"
    .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
 End With
End Sub

Function MyFunctionWithParameter(rng)
    MsgBox (rng)
End Function
```

Comment: tnx for the hint. Maybe is better to pull out this rng as global variable because rng is Selection, and I use it often in other functions and Subs?

Comment: @Stefan89BEG: Maybe. But it depends on what you really are trying to achieve. From the name `ContextMenu` I suspect this `CommandBar` is a context menu. And as of your code the `rng` is the `Selection` at the time of **setting** the new context menu command button. So also the address should be sufficient. If you need the `Selection` at the time of **opening** the context menu, why not simply getting it then?